# Cannot Switch to new browser Window after click button C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have situation when click on button opens new browser window. I try switch to it new window this way :

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

But It does not work.  There is error

> 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below:-

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.ToList().Last());
```